# dropShadow for svg path in flutter

Tags: svg, flutter

I tried Applying DropShadow for a path as mentioned on many websites for existing platforms (i.e [like this one](https://riptutorial.com/svg/example/12622/shadow-filters--basic-dropshadow) or [like w3Schools explained](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_feoffset.asp))

but flutter wasn't rendering that at all , browsers showed some of them (when opened locally on pc), or some of them were visible only in javaScript(!?not sure) powered codeLabs their own website (w3schools) provided

still trying to do this via svg elements without base64 images embeded inside svg as drop shadow as it's a little tricky to work with.

has someOne tried this before?

:hearts

**this is my svg file (without dropShadow) :**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 10.428 10.062">
        <g transform="translate(0 2) rotate(-30)" fill="#ee8c8c">
            <path d="M 7.138411045074463 6.5 L 0.8615883588790894 6.5 L 3.999999761581421 1.007779955863953 L 7.138411045074463 6.5 Z" stroke="none"/>
            <path d="M 3.999999761581421 2.015560150146484 L 1.723176956176758 6 L 6.276822566986084 6 L 3.999999761581421 2.015560150146484 M 3.999999761581421 0 L 8 7 L -4.76837158203125e-07 7 L 3.999999761581421 0 Z" stroke="none" fill="#ee8c8c"/>
        </g>
</svg>
```

**this is one of the methods I tried already :**

```
<svg>

  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
      <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="red"/>
      <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter> 
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(0 2) rotate(-30)" fill="#ee8c8c" filter="url(#drop-shadow)">
    <path d="M 7.138411045074463 6.5 L 0.8615883588790894 6.5 L 3.999999761581421 1.007779955863953 L 7.138411045074463 6.5 Z" stroke="none"/>
    <path d="M 3.999999761581421 2.015560150146484 L 1.723176956176758 6 L 6.276822566986084 6 L 3.999999761581421 2.015560150146484 M 3.999999761581421 0 L 8 7 L -4.76837158203125e-07 7 L 3.999999761581421 0 Z" stroke="none" fill="#ee8c8c" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: there is no drop shadow in this SVG snippet

Comment: @MichaelMullany yes , I meant this is the path if you want to try it yourself .

Comment: I haven't used flutter - but one suggestion might be to add color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to your filter element.

Comment: @MichaelMullany already tried that , thanks , but made no difference to flutter

Answer (score 17):

I was facing this same issue with SVG images, I've just upload a package solving this:
https://pub.dev/packages/simple_shadow

If you are interested in code, here it is:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Transform.translate(
      offset: offset,
      child: ImageFiltered(
        imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: sigma, sigmaX: sigma),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: 0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ColorFiltered(
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcATop),
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child,
  ],
)
```